# Google OAuth 0.2 Invalid Grant

Tags: javascript, google-api, google-api-php-client, google-api-client

I Had the following code

```
$client->setClientId('39605174446-s067746s1jur731n49fujigfh8occ5pa.apps.googleusercontent.com');
$client->setClientSecret('MYCLIENTSECRET');
$client->setRedirectUri('http://examplesss.com/oauth2');
$client->setScopes('https://picasaweb.google.com/data');
$client->setAccessType("offline");
```

I did authenticate

At my Google Console API, I set it for "Web Application", Authorization Javascript origins I leave it blank.

Authorization Redirect URI I set it as

```
http://example.com/oauth2
```

I went to the following site to get my authorisation code

```
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?access_type=offline&approval_prompt=&client_id=39605174446-s067746s1jur731n49fujigfh8occ5pa.apps.googleusercontent.com&redirect_uri=http://example.com/oauth2&response_type=code&scope=https://picasaweb.google.com/data&state=state
```

When I went into the site, I press ok to grant "offline access" . After that I am redirect to an none existent site which I use that is example.com and then the URI was something like

```
http://example.com/oauth2?state=stat&code=4/qWt9q19VtilG6Iw6HFte4RnpiXR0a5q80_zQAU-hNqc#

$client->authenticate('4/qWt9q19VtilG6Iw6HFte4RnpiXR0a5q80_zQAU-hNqc#');
```

Then I get my refresh token code

```
$client->refreshToken('1\/vYnZlRcvaY2nD0yh5LhU9paLZZggMArGOo-3rEJHGCM');
```

But when I run the code it say...

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'Google_Auth_Exception' with message 'Error refreshing the OAuth2 token, message: '{
  "error" : "invalid_grant"
```

Wonder what went wrong, I just want to access my picasa web album.

**Thanks**

Answer (score 0):

It can be 2 things. One, is the incorrect use of the versions of the Google API client or the one I think that is the problem, it's on the refresh token and how you're passing the token. It's a problem with the / character in the string, json enconding and how it's passed. Put the refresh token in double quotes and send the variable. If all the data is correct and authorized via Google, it should work.